# Xvfb virtual display error, no module named fcntl

Tags: python, xvfb, splinter, fcntl

Im trying to make a virtual display for a splinter script. When i runi get the error code "ImportError: No module named 'fcntl'"

```
from splinter import Browser
from xvfbwrapper import Xvfb
vdisplay = Xvfb(width=1280, height=740)
vdisplay.start()
browser = Browser('chrome')
```

What am i doing wrong , or should i be using some alternative virtualdisplay thing